# Passing by reference does not change the variable

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

I am trying to implement a function to change state of the menu, but my reference is lost when it leaves the function:

```
void gotoLowerlevel(Menu *item)
{
    if (item->chld != 0x00) {
        item = item->chld;
    }
}
```

The function call is done in this manner (`currentState` is a pointer to `struct Menu`):

```
case ENTER:
    if (cnsle->inMenuFlag == 0)
    {
        cnsle->inMenuFlag = 1;
        cnsle->currentState = cnsle->root;
        gotoLowerlevel(cnsle->currentState);
        displayMenu(cnsle->currentState,&cnsle->display);
    }
```

I have no idea why this isn't working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`item` in `gotoLowerLevel` is a local variable even if it is a reference to an object elsewhere.  To modify `cnsle->currentState` you need to either:

- pass in `cnsle`
- pass in a reference to `cnsle->currentState` (that is change the method signature to `Menu ** itemptr` and the call parameter to `&cnsle->currentState`)
- or return the new value from `gotoLowerLevel` and assign it: `cnsle->currentState = gotoLowerLevel(cnsle->currentState)`

My preference would be the last option, as this makes it clear when reading the calling code that `currentState` may be modified.

Others have explained how to pass a reference. Code for my preferred solutions is:

```
Menu* gotoLowerlevel(Menu *item)
{
    if (item->chld != 0x00) {
        item = item->chld;
    }
    return item;
}

/* .... */
cnsle->currentState = gotoLowerlevel(cnsle->currentState);
```

Comment: you might also want to check for NULL

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the pointer by value.

Operations on the object it points to will be visible to the outside, but the pointer itself is only a copy.

You might want to use a pointer to pointer.