# linked list the head always is set to NULL

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to add domino tales into a linked list but each time I make a call to the function `add_domino(struct Domino *list, int a ,int b)` the head always stays `NULL`:

```
void add_domino(struct Domino *list, int a ,int b) {
    struct Domino *D = malloc(sizeof(struct Domino));
    D->a = a;
    D->b = b;
    D->next = NULL;

    if(list == NULL) {
        list = D;
    } else {
        struct Domino *p;
        p = list;
        while(p->next != NULL) {
            p = p->next;
        }
        p->next = D;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: head is already a pointer!

struct Domino *head = NULL;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass by reference not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938412/pass-by-reference-not-working)

Comment: You either need to pass a pointer to pointer to the function or return a pointer to the new head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the return with the updated pointer to the head.

```
struct Domino* add_domino(struct Domino *list, int a ,int b) {
    struct Domino *D = malloc(sizeof(struct Domino));
    D->a = a;
    D->b = b;
    D->next = NULL;

    if(list == NULL) {
        list = D;
        return list;
    } else {
        struct Domino *p;
        p = list;
        while(p->next != NULL) {
            p = p->next;
        }
        p->next = D;
    }
  return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either return the updated head-pointer, and use it like:

```
struct Domino* list = NULL;
list = add_domino(list, 1, 2);
```

Or pass a pointer to pointer, and use it like:

```
struct Domino* list = NULL;
add_domino(&list, 1, 2);
```

In addition, your function does not handle insufficient memory.

Next, prefer `sizeof *pointer` over `sizeof(TYPE)`, as repetition is error-prone, especially where the compiler does not check for mismatches.

And finally, consider adding at the head instead of tail, to avoid repeatedly traversing the whole list. Reversing the list at the end if needed is an O(n) constant space operation.